# Read file path from javascript variable and send it to form action?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, web-applications

code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function showFileName() {
              var filename = document.getElementById("uploadFile");
      }
</script>
```

OR

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      var filename = document.getElementById("uploadFile");

</script>
```

OR

```
var filename="uploadedfilename";

<form name="AttachmentsForm" method="post"  action="<%=Constants.WEB_APP_NAME%><%=Constants.SERVLET_NAME%>?para=ajaxRefTabUpload&action=add&uploadfilename="+filename+"" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
    <table class="innerBorderTable" width="100%">
       <tr>                                
    <td>Attach New File:</td>
    <td>
      <INPUT TYPE="FILE" NAME="uploadFile" width="120"> 
      <input type="submit" class="button" value="Add Attachment">
    </td>      
       </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I tried 3 different approaches to pass it with `+filename+` i am getting `null` with `uploadfilename` in action parameter

Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> use of scriptlets(`<% %>`) in JSP highly discouraged, use [JSTL](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl/1.2)(`<c:tags`) or Expression Language(`${}`)

to use JSTL in your jsp download [jstl.x.x.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl/1.2) file and add it to your buildpath.

then, add this

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

in top of jsp.

---

to resolve form action url you have:

```
<%=Constants.WEB_APP_NAME%><%=Constants.SERVLET_NAME%>
```

no need of any constants for that, instead use `<c:url` tag to resolve url like:

```
<c:url value="/yourServletUrl" var="postUrl"/>
<form action="${postUrl}"  method="post" ...
```

> i am getting null with uploadfilename in action parameter

because, you accessing javascript variable in html(`&uploadfilename="+filename+"`), instead do like:

**jsp**:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>your title</title>
</head>
<body>

<c:url value="/yourServletUrl" var="postUrl"/>
<form id="AttachmentsForm"
      method="post"
      onSubmit="showFileName()"
      action="${postUrl}para=ajaxRefTabUpload&action=add"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <table class="innerBorderTable" width="100%">
       <tr>                                
         <td>Attach New File:</td>
         <td>
           <input type="file" name="uploadFile" width="120"> 
           <input type="submit" class="button" value="Add Attachment">
         </td>      
       </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
     function showFileName(e) {

         if (e.preventDefault)
             e.preventDefault();

         var filename = document.getElementById("uploadFile");
         alert('fileName: '+filename);

         //here, attach filename to from action and continue your form submition by AJAX

          // You must return false to prevent the default form behavior
          return false;
        }
      }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
function showFileName() { 
    document.forms[0].action ="<%=Constants.WEB_APP_NAME%>... //Here goes the expression you want to set the action to
}
```

Comment: i am trying like this but when i clicked on add attachment action is not taking place <script type="text/javascript">
    function showFileName() {
              var filename = document.getElementById("uploadFile");
              document.forms[2].action ="<%=Constants.WEB_APP_NAME%><%=Constants.SERVLET_NAME%>?para=ajaxRefTabUpload&action=add&uploadfilename="+filename+"";
     }
</script>

<form name="AttachmentsForm" method="post" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">

Comment: Don't use an input with type=submit, use a button, and make the submit from the javaScript code.

Comment: i am getting null value again with uploadFilefunction showFileName() {
              var filename = document.getElementById("uploadFile");
              document.forms[2].action ="<%=Constants.WEB_APP_NAME%><%=Constants.SERVLET_NAME%>?para=ajaxRefTabUpload&action=add&uploadfilename="+filename+"";
     document.AttachmentsForm.submit();
     }